# USB driver for STM32l100rc using HAL library

Tags: c, usb, stm32

Is there anyone who has worked on STM32L1 series. I'm working on STM32L1xx series and wanted to write USB driver for it. Is there any example for USB driver for STM32L series or anyone worked on STM32L1xx series? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need these works to do:
1.USB client driver on STM32. There are lots of available codes in github or other website;
2.SDcard driver. Normally SDCard has two modes, include SPI mode and SD mode, the operation will be simplified a lot in SPI mode, however, in SD mode the speed will more faster than SPI mode. you can refer to datasheet for more information.

Answer (score 0):

- Download STM32CubeMX
- Download STM32CubeL1
- Start new project for your device, choose peripheral, choose device class for MSC
- Setup clock for USB
- Export project
- Configure SPI for your SDCARD (SDIO is not available) for interface between USB device stack and SDCARD sector read on PC demand.

This are key steps to do, as I don't know what you know so far (looks like nothing) and what you have learn yourself so far (looks like nothing) I'm unable to give you comprehensive answer.